# jQuery selector performance : a curious case

Tags: jquery, performance, testing, jquery-selectors, jsperf

I tested the differences between 2 ID selectors, the first is normal : `$('#lol')`
And the second is the same but placed between multiple parenthesis : `$((((('#lol')))))`

I launched a test on jsperf, with firefox and chrome.
Results are interesting :
With firefox, the first (normal selector) is 40% slower (!!!).
With chrome, the second is 0.84% slower.

Why such a difference ? Can someone explain this ?

Is jsperf.com reliable ?

You can see the test here :

http://jsperf.com/ghshshsrd

I will test on others browsers, for fun.

(Edit: i'm on Mac OS X, by the way)

Comment: Also tested with opera and safari, no real differences. Only firefox has this strange result

Comment: not if you run the test from Firefox browswer, for me both are similar

Comment: I think the projected result shown in the graph is the culprit

Comment: I tested again and again, and the second is still better, but there is less differences (8% fastest).
I don't know if the problem is my firefox or jsperf.

Comment: Why would you call `.html()` if you want to test `$()`? The `.html()` call will completely eclipse any differences, if there was any.

Comment: Try disabling Java Applet plugin in Firefox, the results will be similar.

Comment: @undefined : Java was already disabled. If i activate it, the difference is bigger :D

Comment: @esailja : I first tested selectors only, the results were also strange, so i added .html() to see and nothing changed...

Comment: With FireFox 15, there is no consistent or significant difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the differences between the results obtained for the two statements is negligible. Even when [testing the same statement twice](http://jsperf.com/ghshshsrd-same), it is very unlikely you will yield two identical Ops/sec values.

Also noticed you said "a test", not "multiple tests". If the result seemed odd, just repeat the test - don't forget anomalous results could occur if your browser was starved of resource part way through a test run.

JSPerf has always been reliable for me - enough to be useful for demonstrating optimization techniques ([this being a classic example](http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/5)).

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no real difference between both ways to select an element (except for readability). 
I created a new jsperf test case which more objectively measures the case:

-> http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-performance-20130730

Why your test-result is so strange? It is more likely that your test-scenario is inaccurate than any real performance difference between both tests

You can go and REVERSE the test order of your initial test: first check the code `$(((('#lol'))))` and after this `$('#lol')`.
I am quite certain that you will get the exact opposite result of your current test ;-)

I am not an expert on this, but for one part, the browsers are very smart today and will cache javascript code/variables. Also jQuery possibly will store the value after the first call.